# Как опубликовать сайт на Laravel?

Tags: laravel, сервер, веб-сервер

Имеется домашний сервер на котором есть сайт созданный при помощи фреймворка laravel, что нужно сделать что бы он был виден по внешнему ип?

- порты 80, 8000 проброшены в роутере (TP-Link TL-WR741ND)
- php artisan serve запущен
- на 127.0.0.1:8000 сайт виден
- в локальной сети сайт не виден (т.е. 192.168.0.104:8000 не работает)
- ddns успешно подключен и пробит в роутере

в тоже время апач вден как в локальной так и во внешней сети, в чем причина?

ps: после удаления проброшенных портов в роутере апач все равно откликается..

Comment: `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080`

Comment: @KostaB. благодарю Вас! Добавьте как ответ отмечу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порт и хост, можно менять.

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```